# MYSQL joins to produce correct result

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have a query that joins a few tables together and brings me back a set of results. However i have found that this needs to be tweaked to pull back the results in a different way.

Essentially people have completed a survey which the data is stored into the database.

With the data i need to produce a report like seen in the image below: (this is only a couple of the possible questions for demonstration purposes)

[image]

So the problem i have is for the first question in the image, everyone selected 'yes' which means i have only pulled back that answer. Instead i need to show the possible answer "no" so that i can put 0 on the right(for the amount of people that selected this option).

Ok so the query i have got at the minute is below:

```
            SELECT
                `surveyEntries`.`ID` AS EntryID,
                `surveyEntries`.`created` AS EntryDate,
                `hw_services`.`name` AS Provider,
                `surveyQuestions`.`ID` AS QuestionID,
                `surveyQuestions`.`label` AS Question,
                `survey_meta`.`answer` AS Answer,
                 count(*) as Total,
                `surveyQuestions`.`parentID` AS ParentQuestion
            FROM `survey`
            JOIN `surveyQuestions`
                ON `survey`.`ID` = `surveyQuestions`.`surveyID`


            JOIN `surveyEntries`
                ON `survey`.`ID` = `surveyEntries`.`surveyID`
            JOIN `survey_meta`
                 ON (`surveyEntries`.`ID` = `survey_meta`.`entryID` AND `surveyQuestions`.`ID` = `survey_meta`.`questionID`)
            JOIN `hw_services`
                ON `surveyEntries`.`hw_serviceID` = `hw_services`.`ID`
            WHERE `hw_services`.`healthwatchID` = '1'
            AND `survey`.`ID` = '1'
            AND `surveyQuestions`.`type` IN ('radio', 'dropdown')
            AND `hw_services`.`ID` = 1697
            GROUP BY `surveyQuestions`.`ID`, `survey_meta`.`answer`
```

from this query the result i get is seen below:(only showing 4 rows for demonstration purposes)

[image]

Ok so you can see my problem. for the question "Do you live in the city of Birmingham' 25/25 people selected yes. so i get no row for the option of 'No'.

Okay so the table which has all the options is called questionChoices and a picture is seen below as an example:

[image]

I have tried but have had no luck with getting the result i want. And i really do not want to do this through php as it will make extremely messy code.

Does anyone know how i can achieve this? To help you guys i will provide a list of images showing an example from each database table related to this.

**survey:**

[image]

**surveyEntries:**

[image]

**surveyQuestions:**

[image]

**survey_meta:** (to join questions with answers)

[image]

and i have give an example of **questionChoices** earlier in this question

Comment: You should probably do a `left join` instead of a `join` (which is an `inner join`)

Comment: for all of the joins do you mean?

Comment: Probably, yeah, at least (from top to bottom) up to the join to `hw_services`. Remember, a left join followed by an inner join is essentially an inner join too.

Comment: okay i have tested and produces the same result. do you have an idea of how i could resolve my question?

Comment: If left joins don't fix it, no, not of the top of my head. I'm not familiar with mysql, I don't know how it handles null. You could try grouping by all non-aggregated columns (its stupid mysql allows this anyway), and catch the nulls (ISNULL or mysql's equivalent).

Comment: Could you add a fiddle (sqlfiddle.com) and/or more info about the Primary/Foreign Key relations of all this tables (including `hw_services`)?

Comment: the primary keys are all ID on every table, as for foreign keys you can see in the query in my question in the joins which keys match. the surveyQuestions will be `surveyQuestions`.`surveyID` = `survey`.`ID`

Comment: Your data model is confusing as you got `surveyID` and `healthwatchID` in multiple tables, so the necessary  join order is unclear. E.g. are the `surveyID` always the same for a given row in survey_meta? Without knowing the exact order of joins it's hard to tell where you need Outer joins.

Comment: im sorry, i didn't develop this database schema etc... just been thrown onto an old project, also im a junior developer with limited knowledge of mysql. the surveyID will always be relating to the ID within survey table. healthwatchID will be the same on each table. it relates to an ID on a table that is not related to this whole process so dont need to worry about that